# Finite spanning set of a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I am currently looking at a set of polynomials that looks like this:

$$S = \{p_0 + p_{1}x + p_{2}x^2 + p_{3}x^3 \in P_3 | p_0 = p_1 = 5p_3\} $$

$$ V = p_3$$

V is a vector space and S represents a subspace of V. 
How can I go about determining the finite spanning set of this? I'm been re-reading my textbook for over an hour and I am just so confused!

Comment: Welcome to the website. Look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a tutorial on Mathjax.

Comment: what is $V$? is that some vector space?

Comment: @Jneven Probably polynomials with real coefficients and degree $3$ or less, i.e. $P_3(x)$.

Comment: @Jneven V is a vector space and S (the set of polynomials) is a subspace of V.

Comment: @iam so you should write this in the question as this are important details

Comment: Do you want to describe $S$ as Span of $V$?

Comment: Do you want to describe $S$ as Span of $V$?

Answer (score 0):

$p_0=p_1=5p_3\implies p_0+p_1x+p_2x^2+p_3x^3=p_0(1+x+\dfrac{x^3}5)+p_2x^2$. Thus, $S$ is spanned by the vectors $1+x+\dfrac{x^3}5,x^2$.